# Clashing between two postgres database though having two different docker-compose yaml files for django projects

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am running two different `django` projects in my machine. My machine is running on os -`ubuntu 16.04`.

I am very new to `docker`. As far as I know, the only way to differentiate between two projects setup is defining different containers. To have different containers, I have given different `container_name` in my `docker-compose.yml` file. So, basically, I do have different containers name for two different project and I have used different `postgres` database name in settings.py file for the each project as well.

Following are two different `docker-compose.yml` file configurations

`PROJECT - 1`

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: NGINX_P1
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    container_name: DJANGO_P1
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn safersit.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - /static:/static
    expose:
      - "8000"

  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: PSQL_P1
```

And, the settings.py file for project-1 is :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres_test',  <--- different name for postgres
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

For `PROJECT - 2`

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: NGINX_P2
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    container_name: DJANGO_P2
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn safersit.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - /static:/static
    expose:
      - "8000"

  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: PSQL_P2
```

And, the settings.py file for project-2 is as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

The project-1 is already setup and running well. But, when I try to run the second project, it is giving following error:

```
DJANGO_P2 | users.User.numbers: (models.E006) The field 'numbers' clashes with the field 'numbers' from model 'users.user'.
```

I don't have any field named `numbers` in my seconds project users model, but it is trying to access it from my first project (project-1). I am very confused right now with this set up. Am I doing it right way? Why is my second project trying to access database from first one, even though I do have different container name and database name?

`PROJECT-1` folder structure

```
.
├── config
│   ├── nginx
│   └── requirements.pip
├── docker-compose-backup.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── project1
    ├── manage.py
    ├── messages
    └── users
```

`PROJECT-2` folder structure:

```
.
├── config
│   ├── nginx
│   └── requirements.pip
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── manage.py
    ├── project2
    └── users
```

And the running containers list from both projects is as follows :

```
docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
1f12e1f78ce3        nginx:latest         "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   21 minutes ago      Exited (0) 11 minutes ago                    NGINX_P1
6c20c4a10a8a        project1server_web       "bash -c 'python m..."   About an hour ago   Up 23 minutes                  
 8000/tcp              DJANGO_P1
b7781939ce29        postgres:latest      "docker-entrypoint..."   About an hour ago   Up 23 minutes                   
5432/tcp               PSQL_P1
4600da6f7d29        nginx:latest         "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   9 hours ago         Exited (0) 9 minutes ago                    NGINX_P2
3069796edfd5        project2server_web   "bash -c 'python m..."   9 hours ago         Restarting (1) 14 minutes ago                    DJANGO_P2
3be863184995        postgres:latest      "docker-entrypoint..."   9 hours ago         Up About an hour                5432/tcp                    PSQL_P2
```

I will be grateful for your guidance.

Comment: I believe your HOST setting should be the container name, not 'db'

Comment: Also make sure you are exposing the port 5432 for the 'db' containers

Comment: In later `docker-compose`, the service names are also available as DNS names, so `db` should be fine. Can you give us some more information on the folder structure for the projects and also let us know the output of `docker ps -a` when running both Compose projects? I'm wondering if there is a container name clash and the wrong container is getting linked.

Comment: Hi @AndyShinn, I have updated the folder structure and the containers list from both projects have same values. Please find the NAMES column at the end of the list.